# Is there any support in spring data Redis to pass sentinel username for ACL feature?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-sentinel

Redis is running in HA mode with Sentinel setup.
Redis and Sentinel instances are running with respective ACL user and the default user is turned off.

spring data redis 2.5.4 allow us to pass the below details in sentinel mode:

```
 1.redis username
 2.redis password
 3.redis sentinel password
```

But there is not support for passing

```
  1.sentinel username
```

In JedisConnectionFactory class

```
private JedisClientConfig createSentinelClientConfig(SentinelConfiguration sentinelConfiguration){
return createClientConfig(0,null,sentinelConfiguration.getSentinelPassword());
}
```

Here they are passing "null" directly for sentinel user name and there is no setter for populating sentinel username.

Hence we are not able to connect with the redis server which requires sentinel username to establish the connection in sentinel mode.